# How to make numpy array color similarity conversion

Tags: python, numpy

If a have a numpy array and its shape is (1920,1080,3), how can I change all pixels similar to green to exactly (0,255,0)?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by similar, Maybe use 2 "for" cycles to go through all pixels and in each one use an "if" statement to check if the middle value is bigger than let's say 200, and the others are lower than let's say 50

Comment: Do you want the coords for the pixel with this conf ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean by 'close' is very important. I consider a pixel 'close' to green if the `L_2` norm of the pixel from perfect green is less than `50`. Using such a criterion you can make the replacement efficiently using vectorized methods. In this case, using a boolean mask which is `True` everywhere pixels are close and `False` everywhere they aren't.

```
import numpy as np 

# first make a test image

nx = ny = 300 # dimensions of image
green = np.array([0,255,0]) # perfect green 
im = np.random.randint(0,255,size=(nx,ny,3)) # make a fake image 


# now we make a boolean mask with shape (nx, ny) 
# it is true everywhere the L_2 distance between a pixel in im and a
# perfect green is less than 50. Here's where you need to confine what
# you mean by 'close'

mask = np.sum((im-green)**2,axis=-1) < 50**2 # mask with shape (nx, ny)
im[mask] = green # reassign all close pixels to green
```

Comment: In the last line I got a ValueError "NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 407846 output values where the mask is true" I think it is because we assigned a array(green) to an int. So is there any way to solve it?

Comment: Works now @クロポ. I forgot a sum. This will be fast if you have many images to do this to. However, you need to confine what you mean by close to green.

Answer (score 0):

```
coords = []
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[0])):
        if matrix[i][j][0] == 0 and matrix[i][j][1] == 255 and matrix[i][j][2] == 0:
            coords.append((i, j))
```

I think this isn't efficient, but it works.

Comment: I wrote in a similar way and found it is not efficient enough since I need to process 30 frames per second

Comment: Can you hold all 30 frames in ram at once? The fastest way would be to stack some number `k` frames into a shape `(k, nx, ny, 3)` array, boolean mask the entire thing in a similar way as my response, and then split the masked array into frames over the `0` axis again